# Why is my Binding not updating in XAML

Tags: wpf, data-binding

The following is an example of code I have in WPF.

My view model is being set in the code and my properties are being populated from the database, but my WPF isn't displaying the values even though the view model is correct.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Value}"></TextBox>
```

Code behind example:

```
private readonly MainWindowModel model;
private readonly IMessageService service;

public MainWindow(MainWindowModel model, IMessageService service)
{
    this.model = model;
    this.service = service;
    DataContext = this.model;

    InitializeComponent();
}

protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
{
    model.Value = service.GetLatestMessage();

    base.OnInitialized(e);
}
```

**EDIT**
Fixed example XAML markup

**EDIT**
Added example code-behind

Comment: "*My view model is being set in the code*" - please show us how you do that, also how you assign the DataContext of the view, and how the property is implemented. That said, the XAML in your question isn't valid. A Label has no Text property.

Comment: I think I just found the issue. My MainWindowModel wasn't implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface...

Comment: Then you may just delete the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface within your 'MainWindowModel' and make sure the DataContext is assigned correctly to the view.